# generating unrecognizable image to fool vggnet

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I am trying to generate an unrecognizable image which can fool Vggnet. I used the following vgg model for tensorflow. I add some modification for calculating the gradient. In the ending part, you can see my modification for calculating the gradient respect to the given image (is it correct? I am trying to generate an image to whom the vggnet assign high probability at class 1). With this gradient, I update the random image for fooling the vggnet. But this is not so successful. I can't generate an image with high probability. The maximum probability I got is around 0.001. How can I make it keep increasing?

[image].

**Vggnet model**

#

```
# Davi Frossard, 2016                                                                  #
# VGG16 implementation in TensorFlow                                                   #
# Details:                                                                             #
# http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/post/vgg16/                                      #
#                                                                                      #
# Model from https://gist.github.com/ksimonyan/211839e770f7b538e2d8#file-readme-md     #
# Weights from Caffe converted using https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow      #########################################################################################

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
from imagenet_classes import class_names


class vgg16:
    def __init__(self, imgs, weights=None, sess=None):
        self.imgs = imgs
        self.convlayers()
        self.fc_layers()
        self.probs = tf.nn.softmax(self.fc3l, name= 'prob')
        if weights is not None and sess is not None:
            self.load_weights(weights, sess)

    def convlayers(self):
        self.parameters = []

        # zero-mean input
        with tf.name_scope('preprocess') as scope:
            mean = tf.constant([123.68, 116.779, 103.939], dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 1, 1, 3], name='img_mean')
            images = self.imgs-mean

        # conv1_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv1_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 3, 64], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv1_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv1_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv1_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64, 64], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv1_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[64], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv1_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool1
        self.pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv1_2,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool1')

        # conv2_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv2_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64, 128], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.pool1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[128], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv2_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv2_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv2_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 128, 128], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv2_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[128], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv2_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool2
        self.pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv2_2,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool2')

        # conv3_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv3_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 128, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.pool2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv3_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv3_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv3_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv3_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv3_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv3_3
        with tf.name_scope('conv3_3') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 256], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv3_2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[256], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv3_3 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool3
        self.pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv3_3,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool3')

        # conv4_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv4_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 256, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.pool3, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv4_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv4_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv4_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv4_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv4_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv4_3
        with tf.name_scope('conv4_3') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv4_2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv4_3 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool4
        self.pool4 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv4_3,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool4')

        # conv5_1
        with tf.name_scope('conv5_1') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.pool4, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv5_1 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv5_2
        with tf.name_scope('conv5_2') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv5_1, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv5_2 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # conv5_3
        with tf.name_scope('conv5_3') as scope:
            kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 512, 512], dtype=tf.float32,
                                                     stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(self.conv5_2, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0, shape=[512], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            out = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
            self.conv5_3 = tf.nn.relu(out, name=scope)
            self.parameters += [kernel, biases]

        # pool5
        self.pool5 = tf.nn.max_pool(self.conv5_3,
                               ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                               padding='SAME',
                               name='pool4')

    def fc_layers(self):
        # fc1
        with tf.name_scope('fc1') as scope:
            shape = int(np.prod(self.pool5.get_shape()[1:]))
            fc1w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([shape, 4096],
                                                         dtype=tf.float32,
                                                         stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            fc1b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[4096], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            pool5_flat = tf.reshape(self.pool5, [-1, shape])
            fc1l = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(pool5_flat, fc1w), fc1b)
            self.fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1l)
            self.parameters += [fc1w, fc1b]

        # fc2
        with tf.name_scope('fc2') as scope:
            fc2w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4096, 4096],
                                                         dtype=tf.float32,
                                                         stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            fc2b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[4096], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            fc2l = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(self.fc1, fc2w), fc2b)
            self.fc2 = tf.nn.relu(fc2l)
            self.parameters += [fc2w, fc2b]

        # fc3
        with tf.name_scope('fc3') as scope:
            fc3w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([4096, 1000],
                                                         dtype=tf.float32,
                                                         stddev=1e-1), name='weights')
            fc3b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1000], dtype=tf.float32),
                                 trainable=True, name='biases')
            self.fc3l = tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(self.fc2, fc3w), fc3b)
            self.parameters += [fc3w, fc3b]

        ###################### Modified part######################
        with tf.name_scope('grad') as scope:
            temp =  np.zeros(1000)
            temp[0] = 1
            vec = tf.constant(temp, dtype='float32', name = 'goal')
            loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(tf.nn.softmax(self.fc3l), vec)))
            self.grad = tf.gradients(loss, self.imgs)[-1]
    ##############################################################
    def load_weights(self, weight_file, sess):
        weights = np.load(weight_file)
        keys = sorted(weights.keys())
        for i, k in enumerate(keys):
            print i, k, np.shape(weights[k])
            sess.run(self.parameters[i].assign(weights[k]))
```

**Create session**

#

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

sess = tf.Session()
imgs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 224, 224, 3])
vgg = vgg16(imgs, 'vgg16_weights.npz', sess)
```

**Generate new image for fooling**

#

```
imarray = np.random.rand(224,224,3) * 255
imarray = imarray.astype('float32')
feed_dict = {vgg.imgs: [imarray]}

prob_list = []
prob_list.append(sess.run(vgg.probs, feed_dict={vgg.imgs: [imarray]})[0][0])


lamda = 0.1
#mean = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939])
print 'start'
for i in range(1000):
    rst = sess.run(vgg.grad, feed_dict)
    imarray -= lamda * (rst[0]*255)
    feed_dict = {vgg.imgs: [imarray]}
    prob_list.append(sess.run(vgg.probs, feed_dict={vgg.imgs: [imarray]})[0][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that the shapes of the gradient and the image match.
You are taking the derivative of the loss with respect to the parameters, is should be with respect to the image placeholder. Excuse me, if I'm missing something obvious, I can't run the code right now.

The computation of the loss is based on `fc3l`, the final output is `probs`. I don't see where `probs` is computed in the VGG code. Maybe there are layers in between. You could plot the first component of `fc3l` instead, see if that goes up.

You should probably base the loss on `probs`.

Comment: Yes. You are right about probs. I changed it by adding a softmax to fc3l. However, the results is not getting better.  You can check the modified part for the way how I calculate the gradient. Thanks.

Comment: Could you change the evaluation code, the last line, to sess.run(vgg.fc3l, ...)  ? And could you try to use another code for the gradient: self.grad = tf.gradients(loss, self.imgs)[-1]. I'm sure that this is some stupid misunderstanding on my side - the shapes match otherwise you couldn't substract the gradient from imarray, but I would like to see this.

Comment: changing self.imgs also returns the gradient. I think it is more memory efficient than my way. And I changed the evaluation code to the vgg.fc3l,  I can see the obvious changing in the graph as I expected. However, I can't use fc3l for fooling the fooling the vggnet. It should be the prob layer. However the prob layer does not work.

Comment: Ok, so at least the optimization process works as expected: If you change the gradient and look at the fc3l activations, the graph grows. I don't understand why the network is not fooled. Could you post some concrete results ? Prediction for an image. Then running your algorithm. Prediction for the modified image.